# variable en 'String'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero poner un trozo de codigo html en un return pero dentro del codigo una variable y me salta el siguiente error por consola:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

la variable que quiero introducir es sumMinutos, y ya esta declarada e inicializada

```
$("#canjeador").append(function() {


            return '<div> <p><input type="checkbox" value="240" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Factoría Digital: Industria 4.0 (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="270" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo""> Transformación Digital - ERP Inteligente (270 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="180" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Cómo Potenciar el Liderazgo (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="225" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Encuentro de empresas andaluzas (225 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="240" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Oportunidades del Entorno Digital (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="240" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Costes transporte marítimo internacional (240 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="120" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> FP Sector Aeroespacial (120 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="180" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Presentación Tactiómetro 2019 (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="180" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Gemelo Digital (180 mins)</p> <p><input type="checkbox" value="90" onclick="contadorTiempoRestante()" class="checkboxTiempo"> Cómo ganar dinero con tu blog y redes (90 mins)</p> <span id="comentariobtn">Tiempo disponible: </span> <button type="button" id="btnActividades"> <span class="totalMin" style="display:none">'sumMinutos'</span> <span class="convertedHour">0</span> H <span class="convertedMin">0</span> ´ </button> <button type="button"><span>CANJEA TU TIEMPO</span> </button> </div>'


        });
```

Comment: Como se puede concluir de las soluciones que te ofrecen tu error fue **no concatenar** correctamente la variable. Necesitabas usar el operador de concatenación `+` (respuesta de @NicolaTesla) o insertarla en una **cadena plantilla** (respuesta de @Lobos) agrego el comentario porque ninguno de los dos hizo referencia explícita al error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner variables en cadenas se debe usar el backtick `` en lugar de comillas y la variable va entre `${}`

```js
let variable = 'hola';
let cadena = `texto en cadena más variable ${variable}`;
console.log(cadena);
```

Comment: Una respuesta precisa! Sería bueno agregar una referencia a las [cadenas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Cadenas_literales) para que tanto OP como los futuros lectores de tu solución tengan orientación adicional.

Answer (score 1):

¡Si bien te recomiendo usar los **Template Literal  ``** como lo indica la respuesta anterior, tambien puedes hacer lo siguiente

```js
let variable = 'Hola mundo !!';
let cadena = 'Hola voy a añadir la siguiente variable: '+variable+' ¡Listo quedo añadida!';
console.log(cadena);
```